# GMail API - Can I send email using the Service Account?

Tags: gmail-api

When I send an email using the GMail API, I get an Access Token for the user to whom the message is to be sent and then when sending the message, I put some value in the From Field.

But no matter what I put in the from field, the message in the email shows as From "Me" and is in the Sent mails as well as Inbox.

Is there a way, I could use the Service Account to send the email, so that it does not show up as From "Me" and is also not in the Sent Mails.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending ?

Comment: long story short - you can not do this with GMail. You can not do this even if you are using Google App and paying for the service.

Answer (score 13):

You **cannot** use a service account to impersonate a **free** gmail account. I spent a lot of time confirming this after reading a reply that was here before. Maybe it worked at some point, but it doesn't anymore.

> There is no way to share / grant another user permission to access
> your standard gmail account. So there is no way for you go delegate
> the permissions for bob@mycompany.com to access bob@gmail.com.

and

> you can impersonate G-Suite accounts but not Gmail accounts

These quotes are from Google's official C# Auth repo:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1561

Comment: My "personal account" is in fact a paid G-suite account. Apologies for the confusion. I'll have to get some code up to demo till then I'm deleting that answer

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to call you out explicitly. I just went down a rabbit hole and didn't want anyone else to do the same. Thanks for you reply.

Comment: no issues, i was VERY sloppy with my words so can understand how this would confuse a lot of people. If I had put the code there, it would have solved a lot of headaches for everyone, myself included.

Comment: You can use service accounts to impersonate only G-suite accounts, earlier known as Google for work, of your domain

Comment: For anyone reading this later, this is what worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention

Answer (score 9):

No.  The Gmail API is for Gmail users and service accounts are just for doing auth to a real Gmail account, they don't have their own Gmail account, etc.

If you want to send the email from some service, you need some bulk-sending email service like at: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/  or something you run yourself or from some other provider.

Answer (score -1):

No, what you are looking for is a bulk email sending service.  Checkout [sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com) , [Amazon AWS SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/), [mandrill](https://www.mandrill.com)  or  if you want to stick with Google, [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/).  You could of course run your own postfix server (although I'm assuming you were using gmail api for deliverability in the first place.