# Can't authenticate Google service account to Gmail

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-api-client, google-oauth, service-accounts

I have a GSuite email address example@gmail.com and I created a Google service account example-sa@iam.gserviceaccount.com.

My goal is to send emails from this SA as if it was the email but I'm not able to authenticate the SA.

I could however login the service account Google Drive with this code:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient import discovery

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'sa-credentials.json'
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)

# code
```

However, when I try to do the same for gmail I get an error:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient import discovery

SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'sa-credentials.json'
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)

profile = service.users().getProfile(userId='me').execute()
```

The error:

> ```
>     raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/profile?alt=json returned "Bad Request">
> ```

If I click on the URL provided in the error message I get:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this similar question:  [GMail API - Can I send email using the Service Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233694/gmail-api-can-i-send-email-using-the-service-account)

> No. The Gmail API is for Gmail users and **service accounts are just for
>   doing auth to a real Gmail account, they don't have their own Gmail
>   account**, etc.

In other words, the service account doesn't appear to be a Gmail mailbox that you can access.

You need to use the service account to access some *other* mailbox, and to do that, you need to do one of two things:

1. Use a Oauth2 flow to get the owner of the mailbox you wish to use to grant access (see:  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server)

OR

2. If you control / own the Gsuite domain, grant domain-wide authority for that domain to your service account.  See:  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation