Authenticate using Oauth2 to Gmail SMTP
Since Google is going to drop the support for PLAIN authentication in their SMTP I want to migrate to OAuth2 based authentication.
Following this documentation I started with setting up a service account and creating keys in json format.
Then tried to authenticate using this code:

import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials;
import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport;
import jakarta.mail.Session;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ForSendingEmailOauthAdapater {

  void send() throws Exception {
    InputStream secret = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("keys.json");
    String email = "myemail@test.com"; // in my production code this set to the related service account email
    GoogleCredentials credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(secret)
        .createScoped(Collections.singletonList("https://mail.google.com/"));
    credentials.refreshIfExpired();
    String token = credentials
        .getAccessToken()
        .getTokenValue();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp", "true");
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
    session.setDebug(true);

    SMTPTransport transport = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, email, null);

    String authString = "user=" + email + "\001auth=Bearer " + token + "\001\001";
    String base64oauth2String = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authString.getBytes());
    transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + base64oauth2String, 235);
  }
}

Unfortunately it fails:
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
EHLO <myhostname>
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [89.64.21.109]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
AUTH XOAUTH2 <base64 encoded user&token>
555-5.5.2 Syntax error, goodbye. For more information, go to
555-5.5.2  https://support.google.com/a/answer/3221692 and review RFC 5321
555 5.5.2 specifications. a640c23a62f3a-a725f5e1b52sm262436666b.135 - gsmtp

It looks pretty much the same as in here (see SMTP section).
The 555-5.5.2 error suggests it's an invalid email address (e.g. recipient's), but it fails at auth, not event getting to sending the email.
I have also tried the same via curl but it failed with the same error:
  curl -sv --url 'smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587' \
  --ssl-reqd \
  --login-options 'AUTH=XOAUTH2' --oauth2-bearer <access_token> \
  --user <service account email> \
  --mail-from test@test.com --mail-rcpt test@test.com

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

You can't send an email with service account please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233694/gmail-api-can-i-send-email-using-the-service-account

Are you still having issues with this?
What seems odd to me is that you are trying to authenticate directly with the service account. Which is likely the cause of the issue since it's not a gmail account (smtp.gmail.com is the gmail smtp server).
The guide you link explains how to then use the service account to impersonate users (workspace only).
You should try to use instead a consent screen to authenticate as a gmail user and obtain the token, then send that in the xoauth2 authentication.
Take a look at the Gmail API quickstart for java you can use the authentication flow from it to login as a gmail user, then use the rest of your code. I know you don't want to use the Gmail API, I'm just linking this sample since the authentication process is relevant to your use case.
